# Function to equation

Tags: function, recursion, equation

Given a function fun, what is the mathematical equation for Rec?

```
public class Fun {

  public static int Rec(int n) {

    if ((n==1) || (n==2))
      return 1;
    else {
      int result = 0;
      for(int i=2; i<=(n-1); i++)
        result = result+Rec(n-1)+ Rec(n-2);

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should begin method names with a lowercase letter

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a 'please do my homework' question...

Comment: Can you confirm what language this is for? (Presumably C#?)

Answer (score 0):

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1
f(3) = 2
f(4) = 6
f(5) = 24
f(6) = 120
f(7) = 720
f(8) = 5040
f(9) = 40320
f(10) = 362880
f(11) = 3628800
```

looks like (n-1)!